# Read dynamic parameters from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, .net-core, appsettings

I am working on the APIExecutor project which is a console application reading the required configuration from the Appsettings.json file. which is like below:

```
  "APIConfig": {
    {
      "RootAPI": "https://hub.dummyapis.com",
      "API": [
        {
          "Url": "/employee",
          "Method": "GET",
          "Params": {
            "noofRecords": 10,
            "idStarts": 1001
          },
          "RequestType": "application/json",
          "Headers": null
        },
        {
          "Url": "/student",
          "Method": "POST",
          "Params": {
            "name": "ABC",
            "adress": "bla bla bla",
            "IsPassed": true,
          },
          "RequestType": "application/json",
          "Headers": null
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I wanted to map it into the following class

```
public class APIConfig {
     public string Url { get; set; }
     public string Method { get; set; }
     public dynamic Params { get; set; }
     public string RequestType { get; set; }
     public List<RequestHeaders> Headers { get; set; }
}
```

In the above parameters, Params can be anything, I don't know what the type of the Params should be, it strictly depends on the API call. So, I tried to make it dynamic and object but when I try to fetch it like below:

```
var config = _builder.GetSection("APIConfig").Get<APIConfig>()
```

Here, _builder is an instance of IConfiguration.

Please Notice: Params are not fixed. It can be any, depending on the API call.

Getting null in the config. I know it is because of the dynamic parameters. If I remove that param then it maps successfully.

I don't find any way to map dynamic parameters while reading configuration from appsettings.json

Comment: What do you want to achieve. Because the file will be loaded once per life time of the app. Or you are writing a library to read all the parameters. Have you tried Object instead of dynamic?

Comment: Yes, still it gives null in config

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gvwsqu. Notice into that, I commented the Params object

Answer (score 2):

try to use these classes using public Dictionary<string,object> Params

```
public class APIConfig
{
    public string RootAPI { get; set; }
    public List<API> API { get; set; }
}
public class API
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Method { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> Params  { get; set; }
    public string RequestType { get; set; }
    public object Headers { get; set; }
}
```

it was tested with this code and working properly

```
APIConfig apiConfig = configuration.GetSection("APIConfig").Get<APIConfig>();
```

but it you want to deserialize json with the nested elements like this

```
"APIConfig": {
    "RootAPI": "https://hub.dummyapis.com",
        "API": [
            {
        "Url": "/employee",
                "Method": "GET",
                "Params": {
                    "noofRecords": 10,
                    "idStarts": 1001,
                    "Items": [
                        {
                       "item1": "value1"
                        },
                        {
                        "item2": "value2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "RequestType": "application/json",
                "Headers": null
            }
        ]
    },
```

you will have to load json directily from the file, since it seems config dowloads only onel level

```
string basePath=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(); // or any else

string json = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(basePath+@"\appsettings.json"))
json = r.ReadToEnd();

    var jsonObject = JObject.Parse(json)["APIConfig"];
    
    var config=jsonObject.ToObject<APIConfig>();
```

test

```
    var items = (JArray) config.API[0].Params["Items"];
    
    foreach (JObject item in items)
    {
        foreach(var val in  item.Properties())
            Console.WriteLine($"Key:  {val.Name}  Value:  {val.Value}");

    }
```

items

```
Key:  item1  Value:  value1
Key:  item2  Value:  value2
```

Comment: My dear, here Params are not fixed. We must take it as dynamic or object

Comment: Thank you @Serge for you efforts, it does not work when param contains list

Comment: @Pls post the example of  appsettings containing list, that is valid

Comment: I updated fiddle. Please check